# How can I use 'piplite' in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to use 'piplite' in my system (VS-Code and jupyter Notebook) but I have an Error. I installed pip and my system is Mac.

```
import piplite
await piplite.install(['pandas'])
await piplite.install(['matplotlib'])
await piplite.install(['numpy'])
await piplite.install(['scikit-learn'])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import piplite
      2 await piplite.install(['pandas'])
      3 await piplite.install(['matplotlib'])

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'piplite'
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `piplite` is installed in the Python environment which ran your code above?